# Emmet abbreviations make multi <a> from existing urls

Tags: html, css, emmet

this urls as:

```
www.google.com
www.yahoo.com
www.instagram.com
www.github.com
```

are in my editor and i want to make some `li` and `a` from them form example:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="www.www.google.com" target="_blank">www.yahoo.com</a></li>
    <li><a href="www.instagram.com" target="_blank">www.instagram.com</a></li>
    <li><a href="www.github.com" target="_blank">www.github.com.com</a></li>
</ul>
```

with this emmet snippet:

```
ul>li*4>a[href="http://www.$#.com" target="_blank"]{http://www.$#.com}
```

but it doesnt work correctly and i get this output:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="http://www.www.google.com
www.yahoo.com
www.instagram.com
www.github.com.com" target="_blank">http://www.www.google.com
        www.yahoo.com
        www.instagram.com
        www.github.com.com</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.www.google.com
www.yahoo.com
www.instagram.com
www.github.com.com" target="_blank">http://www.www.google.com
        www.yahoo.com
        www.instagram.com
        www.github.com.com</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.www.google.com
www.yahoo.com
www.instagram.com
www.github.com.com" target="_blank">http://www.www.google.com
        www.yahoo.com
        www.instagram.com
        www.github.com.com</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.www.google.com
www.yahoo.com
www.instagram.com
www.github.com.com" target="_blank">http://www.www.google.com
        www.yahoo.com
        www.instagram.com
        www.github.com.com</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: what editor are u using?

Comment: @GautamNaik my editor is phpStorm

Comment: can u try by removing the 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
ul>li*>a[href=$# target="_blank"]{http://$#}
```

No need to add a number to multiplier when u have selected the text

More info about  [Here](https://docs.emmet.io/actions/wrap-with-abbreviation/#wrapping-individual-lines)